# Question about the ~ and @ operators in Haskell

Tags: haskell, operator-keyword, primes, sieve

What exactly do they do? I know one possible use of @ (assigning a name at the start of a pattern match), but haven't been able to find anything on ~.

I found them in the following code snippet, taken from http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers, but the article assumes that you're fluent in Haskell syntax and doesn't bother explaining its esoteric operators (the part I'm confused about is the start of the declaration for *sieve*):

```
primesPT () = 2 : primes'
  where 
    primes' = sieve [3,5..] primes' 9
    sieve (p:xs) ps@ ~(_:t) q
       | p < q   = p : sieve xs ps q
       | True    =     sieve [x | x<-xs, rem x p /= 0] t (head t^2)
```

Any explanation (or link to one) about the syntax used here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords is a pretty good place to look up un-Googleable things

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The operator `~` makes a match lazy. Usually a pattern-match evaluates the argument, as there is a need to check whether the pattern fails. If you prefix a pattern with `~`, there is no evaluation until it is needed. This functionality is often used in [“Tying the knot”](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot) code, where one needs to refer to structures that are not yet created. If the pattern fails upon evaulation, the result is `undefined`.

Here is an example:

```
f (_:_) = True
f []    = False

g ~(_:_) = True
g []     = False
```

`f []` yields `False`, while `g []` yields true, because the first pattern always matches. (You actually get a warning for this code)

That said, you can see `~` as the opposite of `!`, which forces the evaluation of an argument even if it's unneeded.

Note that these operators only make things strict/lazy at the level they are applied at, not recursively.  For example:

```
h ~((x,y):xys) = ...
```

The pattern match on the tuple is strict, but the cons pattern is lazy.

Answer (score 9):

It's a [*lazy pattern match*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness#Lazy_pattern_matching) (also known as *irrefutable pattern match* which I think is the better name).

Essentially, `~(_:t)` will always match, even if the input is the empty list `[]`. Of course, this is dangerous if you don't know what you're doing:

```
Prelude> let f ~(_:t) = t in f []
*** Exception: <interactive>:1:4-15: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (_ : t)
```